# Required time to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 because for some reason there was a graphic usage error on 14.04 and it would just not work. So after logging in on the console using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (I don't remember this) I put my login name and password and ran `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

How long does it take for the upgrade to finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time needed for the upgrade to finish depends on many factors like your internet connection speed, the actual download speed you get from the Canonical servers, the type of mass storage in your computer, and even your CPU.

On our somewhat outdated office PC with a regular HDD, it took around 40 minutes give or take, using a 16mbps DSL connection.

Depending on your circumstances, I'd say this might be anywhere from 15 minutes to 1.5 hours in general.